# Ruby_Koan: Number as parameter in regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

For following functions: What does  `[/(\w+), (\w+)/, 1]` mean as whole. (I am assuming that comma does not have a special meaning here). `/(\w+), (\w+)/,`matches a word, a comma, a word and a comma again. How does "1" separate the returned results? What gives 1 the special meaning so it is not a literal anymore?

```
   def test_parentheses_also_capture_matched_content_by_number
     assert_equal "Gray", "Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/, 1]
     assert_equal "James", "Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/, 2]
   end

   def test_variables_can_also_be_used_to_access_captures
     assert_equal "Gray, James", "Name:  Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/]
     assert_equal "Gray", $1
     assert_equal "James", $2
   end
```

How did regex turn string into array?

Comment: It's all in the document.

Comment: In your code, `str[/(\w+), (\w+)/, 1]` is a method call with two arguments, `/(\w+), (\w+)/` and `1`. It's an alias for `str.slice(/(\w+), (\w+)/, 1)`.

Comment: @sawa Good call. I thought [] is a ruby way of applying regex to an object  and did not think of it as a method to extract substring. I was researching regex in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at this variant of [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

```
 str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil
```

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a `capture` follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

This regexp has several match groups/captures. The second parameter specifies which of the captures to return. That's it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the optional second argument. Good to know.

Comment: how does ruby determine the default delimiter(comma, in this case), what if the return data is separated by space instead?

Comment: @aDev: What do you mean, default delimiter? The number is not part of the regex, if you look closer. The regex and the number are just ordinary arguments in a method call. Arguments in a method call are separated with comma.

Comment: I know that it has two arguments. The first part '/(\w+), (\w+)/' returns "Gray, James" and the second argument(1, in this case) will return the first part of result string, which is "Gray". So here, ruby determined the items are separated by the comma in the result string. I am wondering, how doe Ruby know to separate items by comma. What if the result string does not have a comma in it, instead it is something like "Gray James" or "Gray-James". How does ruby determine what separates the item?

Comment: @aDev: the regex contains a comma. And it matches one in the string. If the string didn't contain comma (`"Gray-James"`), regex wouldn't match and you'd get a nil. There's no "delimiters". There are only the regex, its match groups and how your string fits them.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am talking about if the regex is changed in such way that it returns  `"Gray-James"`, will the second argument(still "1" in this case) still be able to separate the string by the hyphen? If so, how does Ruby know

Comment: @aDev sure, why not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156039/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-adev).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Ruby dev but from how regexes work in different languages I would assume that string turns into an array of matches.

Between () in regex is what is called a MATCH GROUP. Results of matched groups are put into arrays AND number is probably an index of match group (you have 2 match groups).

```
   def test_parentheses_also_capture_matched_content_by_number
     assert_equal "Gray", "Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/, 1]
     assert_equal "James", "Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/, 2]
   end
```

So this basically checks if 1st match group is Grah and 2nd is James. If you look at regex you have (word), (word) written in regex form so a 1st word is Gray and second is James.

```
   def test_variables_can_also_be_used_to_access_captures
     assert_equal "Gray, James", "Name:  Gray, James"[/(\w+), (\w+)/]
     assert_equal "Gray", $1
     assert_equal "James", $2
   end
```

Here it seems like you validate asserts of string matching regex then capture groups of that string referred by $1 and $2 matching the hardcoded string words.

Many languages use this notation of matched groups starting at index 1 cause 0 is reserved for entire matched string :)